# Using native queries but maintaining database independence

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

With Spring JPA is there an easy way to use native queries but maintaining  database independence, for example by using the query which fits best?

At the moment I do this by checking the currently set `Dialect` from the `Environment` and call the proper method of my `Repository`:

```
public Foo fetchFoo() {
    if (POSTGRES_DIALECT.equals(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"))) {
      return repo.postgresOptimizedGetFoo();
    }    
    return repo.getFoo();
}
```

This works but I have the feeling that there is a better way or that I am missing something. Especially because (Spring) JPA allows it to use native queries quite easily but that breaks one of its big advantages: database independence.

Comment: Seems way to complicated to me and a lot of if/then/else in your code in a lot of places. That is going to break at some point. Why don't you just use JPQL or optimize the dialect used to create better queries. Or move all the queries to an `orm.xml` and create a special `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` to load a db specific `orm.xml` i.e. `orm-h2.xml` and `orm-postgresql.xml` based on the detected datasource/connection type. That way you can use named queries in your code instead of having the ugly if/then/else checks everywhere. Simplifies your code imho.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, this can be achieved simply by using **@Transactional(readOnly=false)** and then instead of calling **session.createQuery**, one can use **session.createSQLQuery**, as provided in this example. 
Your sql can be any of your native query.
Hope this works for you. :)

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public Long getSeqVal() {
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
String sql = "SELECT nextval('seqName')";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
BigInteger big = (BigInteger) query.list().get(0);
return big.longValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea: I do not know whether it works or not:

My idea would be having subinterfaces, one normal Spring-Data-JPA-interface with all methods for one entiy (without native query hints). Than I would crate a  subinterface for every database, that "override" the database specific native statements. (This intrface would be empty if there are no DB specific statements). Then I would try configure Spring-JPA with some profiles to load the right specific interface (for example by a class-name or package-name-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a way to complicated way to get queries to work.

If you really want to use optimized queries make it at least transparant for your code. I suggest using named queries and create an `orm.xml` per database (much like Spring Boot uses to load the `schema.xml` for a different database).

In your code you can simply do

```
public interface YourRepository extends JpaRepository<YourEntity, Long> {

    List<YourEntity> yourQueryMethod();
}
```

This will look for a named query with the name `YourEntity.yourQueryMethod`. Now in your `orm.xml` add the named query (the default one and in another one the optimized one).

Then you need to configure your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory` to load the specific one needed. Assuming you have a property defining which database you use, lets name it `database.type` you could do something like the following

```
<bean class="LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">        
    <property name="mappingResources" value="classpath:META-INF/orm-${database.type}.xml" />
    ... other config ...
</bean>
```

This way you can keep your code clean of the if/then/else construct and apply where needed. Cleans your code nicely imho.